# Scalable Voltage Display

Tags: current-measurement, display, 7segmentdisplay, voltmeter, scaling

I am trying to create my first PCB, and I am trying to measure and display scaled voltage and current output from a few different sensors on several seven segment displays.

For example, one of the sensors is a pressure transducer that outputs 0.25 - 4.25 V over a 0-30 psi range, and I would like to output "0.000 - 30.000" on the display.

Essentially, I am looking for a saleable millivolt multimeter packaged into a seven-segment display. Is there an easy way to make this?